# How to get more specific errors, Ember Data 422 Error

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I am attempting a post action using Ember-Data, and getting the following error which seems pretty common:

```
 Error: The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid
```

Problem is, seems like usually this returns more specific errors; I am only seeing the above message and a generic 422 error from the browser.

Does anyone know what I can do to access any specific error messages that might be thrown?

Potentially relevant info:

Using [jsonapify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonapify) on an express server to write to MongoDB

```
router.post('/',
    jsonapify.create('info'),
    logger.logErrors(), jsonapify.errorHandler()
);
```

I would expect the following code to log some sort of response but I am never able to see the message in this console.log:

```
info.save().then((response)=> {
        console.log(`Server responded with ${response}`);
      });
```

Sorry for the vagueness here, I'm sure there could be all sorts of problems with my models and whatnot, but I want to know what I can do to find the more specific errors if they exist.

Thanks much and plz lmk if I can update with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.then()` takes two arguments, like so: `.then(success, failure)` the first one being a function to be called on success, and the second to be called on failure. A 422 response is a failure, and your current code only has a success handler, so it will never be called. Basically, copy-paste your current success handler to be the second argument to your `.then()` call.

Also, generally in your browser you can open up the inspector and take a look at the request in the 'network' tab.

Your new debugging code could look something like this:

```
let success = (response) => {
  console.log(`Server responded with ${response}`);
};
let failure = (response) => { 
  debugger; 
};
info.save().then(success, failure);
```

Then you should be able to poke around the response object in your js console and see what's going wrong.

Comment: My hero. Thanks much!